# Creating a date pattern in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a column of dates that increase by week each time. Ex: For this year It starts with 1/04/2016 and then 1/11/2016.

I need The 1/4/2016 date to show up 12 times and then the next week to show up 12 times. So on and so forth for the rest of the year.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: School must be back in session.

Comment: It actually is.  Your question is worded like many of the homework questions that get asked on the site.  When you asked you also didn't state that you had previously tried anything. so... that is why I down voted.

Answer (score 2):

In A1 write 1/04/2016 and in A2 write the following formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=12,A1+7,A1)`

and copy down in the same column

[image]

Comment: The idea from @SuperSam would not work. It would produce 12 x `04-01-2016` then the rest would be `1-11-2016` as it is always taking cell `A1` as the start of the range and counting how many `01-04-2016` dates there are.

Comment: @Chris You've missing something subtle. At each cell, the formula counts how many times the in the date in the previous cell occurs, **not** how many times `01-04-2016` occurs. When the count is 12, the current cell is 7 more than the previous cell. For example, in cell `A37`, `A36` is `18-01-2016`, `18-01-2016` occurs 12 times, so `A37` is `A36 + 7 = 25-01-2016`. The solution works.

Comment: Ah yes.  Very clever @SuperSam

Answer (score 0):

Put 1/4/2016 in the first cell (A1). A2 `=A1` and fill that down through A12. Then in A13 `=A1+7` and fill that down to A24. Then Copy A13:A24 and paste/fill that down until your end date.

[image of formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6a4W.png)